# Appending to a dataframe by moving the grouped month by -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

[image]

I want to have an output as shown above. The code loops through the unique months and then assigns a value to the age and drops the most recent month. For eg first it goes from 2021-06 to 2021-05, and the aging of 2021-05 starts from 1 instead of 2.It takes 2021-05 and 2021-04 and adds it original dataframe. and so on

Answer (score 1):

While the original dataframe is not empty, remove the most recent month, and using only the month (`df.Month.dt.month`) from the remaining dataframe adjust the `Age` column. Append the modified dataframe into a list, and proceed to the remaining rows of the dataframe. After the loop is complete, use `pd.concat` to create a single dataframe with the desired number of rows and `Age` values.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])

group = df.groupby(df['Month'].dt.month)

df_list = [df]
while not df.empty:
    df = df.drop(group.get_group(df.Month.dt.month.max()).index)
    df.Age = df.Age - 1
    df_list.append(df)

df_out = pd.concat(df_list)
print(df_out)
```

Output from *df_out*

```py
       Month  Country Product  Age
0 2021-06-01  Germany     abx  1.0
1 2021-06-01   France     khk  1.0
2 2021-05-01   Lisbon      iu  2.0
3 2021-05-01    Paris    kguy  2.0
4 2021-05-01  Germany     kjb  2.0
5 2021-04-01    China    jhvu  3.0
6 2021-04-01    Hawai     hju  3.0
2 2021-05-01   Lisbon      iu  1.0
3 2021-05-01    Paris    kguy  1.0
4 2021-05-01  Germany     kjb  1.0
5 2021-04-01    China    jhvu  2.0
6 2021-04-01    Hawai     hju  2.0
5 2021-04-01    China    jhvu  1.0
6 2021-04-01    Hawai     hju  1.0
```